# Pushing a new file to a git branch using Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

We are currently migrating our code base from SVN to GitLab and in preparation I am attempting to test some basic functionality between Git and Jenkins.  One of the areas I am having issue with is pushing a new file to Git.

The console log appears as though the push worked as expected however the actual git repo has no record of the push happening.

Here is what is shown in my console:

> Cloning the remote Git repository
>   remote: Counting objects
>   remote: Compressing objects
>   Receiving objects
>   Resolving deltas
>   Updating references
>   Checking out Revision a0523f53acf74c5d4fd464d8b1126102c00fd9ee (origin/master)
>   [test-post-to-git2] $ cmd /c call >C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson741863400083270764.bat
>   [test-post-to-git2] $ cmd /c call >C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson7082713428543839601.bat
>
> F:\Jenkins\workspace\test-post-to-git2>git add .
>
> F:\Jenkins\workspace\test-post-to-git2>git commit -am "adding GitTest.txt" 
>   [localMaster ac6b719] adding GitTest.txt
>    2 files changed, 513 insertions(+), 512 deletions(-)
>    create mode 100644 GitTest.txt
>
> F:\Jenkins\workspace\test-post-to-git2>exit 0 
>   Pushing HEAD to branch master at repo origin
>   Opening connection
>   Counting objects
>   Finding sources
>   Getting sizes
>   Compressing objects
>   Writing objects
>   Finished: SUCCESS

Despite the console showing that it pushed successfully there are no changes found within Git itself.  As I am still learning Git it is entirely possible I am missing something simple.

I forgot to note that I am attempting to push it using Git Publisher rather than a batch command selecting the option to 'Push only if build succeeds', Branch to push is set to 'master', and Target remote name is set to 'origin'.

Comment: Can you copy/paste the content of your batch build step? After the Git commit, do you push your new file in the remote repo? (--> git push origin master)

Comment: I see git add, git commit but no any "git push". Please, show here the batch commands.

Comment: Sorry I am attempting to push it using Git Publisher rather than a batch command selecting the option to 'Push only if build succeeds', Branch to push is set to 'master', and Target remote name is set to 'origin'.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem as thou you have pushed your changed to the remote repository.
Once you do a commit in git, the changes are now in your local repository. To get your changes into the remote repository(the one Jenkins sees) you need to push your changes.

```
git push origin <branchName>
```

Comment: What if I am trying to use Git Publisher as a post build action instead?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it.